# Best Image Size for different layout sizes in Android

Tags: android, image, android-layout

Which is the best size image for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi density in Android?

I am asking because I didn't find any topic about the perfect images size for each density.

For example, the Medium Density is 320X480, 480X800, 480X854, 1280X800, etc.. knowing that I need to draw an image based on a higher size?

Answer (score 5):

> To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you should follow the 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the four generalized densities. For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screen (the size for a launcher icon), all the different sizes should be:
>
> - 36x36 for low-density
> - 48x48 for medium-density
> - 72x72 for high-density
> - 96x96 for extra high-density

From http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: I know this, but I don't know the specific resolution of images, for example: Which is the best resolution to medium density for two screen sizes 320X480 and 480X800, the scale(ratio) for first is 1.5 and for second is 1.666, The Android will scale correctly if I draw a Image based on 480X800 ? maybe not!